# Retrieve mysql entries from a single array or collection

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I've made the following sql query

```
$dates = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT `saledate` FROM `phoneappdetail`");
```

Now I want to echo results in the array like so.

```
$dates[0]
```

I don't want to use a while statement so I can use $date[1], $date[2], ect. in different places on the page.

Comment: What's wrong with `while`? You cannot avoid a `while` loop, so just go with it.

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you want to learn, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still have to use a while loop in order to traverse the result because mysql_query returns a resource and not an array.

```
function getResultArray() {
    $result_array =  array();
    $result_set = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT `saledate` FROM `phoneappdetail`");

    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result_set) ) {
        $result_array[] = $row;
    }

    return $result_array;
}

$date = getResultArray();
echo $date[0]['saledate'];
```

Comment: This looks like what I want but when I run it get back the value '2' when the value is really '2010-04-22'

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to pivot to do that and read all the dates back in one record

Use a while loop read them into an array, then reference that it will be a heck of a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

look at the mysqli_fetch_array() function

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php